# Apache Hadoop is not doing it's combining & reducing work in my program that it should do

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, ubuntu-14.04

I'm a starter in Apache Hadoop and tried Word Counting program from Apache and it worked fine. But now I would like to make my own outdoor temperature program that calculates daily averages. Average calculation is not working as I expected; no combining & averaging of data is made.

To be more specific here is a part of my sample2.txt input file:

```
25022016 00:00:00 -10.3
25022016 00:01:00 -10.3
25022016 00:02:00 -10.3
25022016 00:03:00 -10.3
...
25022016 00:59:00 -11.2
```

and the output that I would like to have should be:

```
25022016 7.9
```

which is the average of all temperature observations of that date. So I have 60 observations and want one average. In the future I'd like to process more observations during more days with the same program. 1. column is date (text), 2. time and third one is temperature. Temperature calculations are done in float data type of Java in the code.

What happens now is that the output is:

```
25022016    -10.3
25022016    -10.3
25022016    -10.3
25022016    -10.3
...
25022016    -11.2
```

so the average is counted of each *one* observation (from one number is calculated the average of one number). I'd like the average (one number) from 60 observations!

So my input and output files are above. My Java code (I run it on Windows 7 -> VirtualBox -> Ubuntu 64-bit) is following:

---

```
package hadoop; 

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;

public class ProcessUnits2 
{ 
    public static class E_EMapper extends
    Mapper<Object, Text, Text, FloatWritable>
    { 
        private FloatWritable temperature = new FloatWritable();
        private Text date = new Text();       

        public void map(Object key, Text value, 
        Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        { 
            StringTokenizer dateTimeTemperatures = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());

            while(dateTimeTemperatures.hasMoreTokens()) {
                date.set(dateTimeTemperatures.nextToken());

                while(dateTimeTemperatures.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    dateTimeTemperatures.nextToken();    
                    temperature.set(Float.parseFloat(dateTimeTemperatures.nextToken()));

                    context.write(date, temperature);
                }
            }
        } 
    } 


    public static class E_EReduce extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,FloatWritable>
    {
        private FloatWritable result = new FloatWritable();

        public void reduce( Text key, Iterable<FloatWritable> values, Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        { 
            float sumTemperatures=0, averageTemperature;
            int countTemperatures=0;

            for (FloatWritable val : values) {
                sumTemperatures += val.get();
                countTemperatures++;
            } 

            averageTemperature = sumTemperatures / countTemperatures;

            result.set(averageTemperature);
            context.write(key, result);

        } 
    }  

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception 
    { 
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

        if (otherArgs.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> [<in>...] <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "VuorokaudenKeskilampotila");
        job.setJarByClass(ProcessUnits2.class);

        job.setMapperClass(E_EMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(E_EReduce.class);
        job.setReducerClass(E_EReduce.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < otherArgs.length - 1; ++i) {
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[i]));
        }
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,
        new Path(otherArgs[otherArgs.length - 1]));
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    } 
} 
---------------------------------------------------
```

Hadoop version is 2.7.2 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I run hadoop in standalone mode (most basic setting).

Here are the commands I use to build the program (if it helps?):

```
rm -rf output2 
javac -Xdiags:verbose -classpath hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d units2 ProcessUnits2.java
jar -cvf units2.jar -C units2/ .
hadoop jar units2.jar   hadoop.ProcessUnits2 input2 output2
cat output2/part-m-00000
```

As a beginner I'm confused and to my mind hadoop is not doing here any combining & reducing (= averaging) work in it's default settings which should be it's most ultimate purpose. I admit that I picked code from here and there (examples) because nothing worked and I'm sure it is only a little step to solution but I cannot guess what it is. I could easily do this with for example C++ without any map reducing -framework at all but the thing is that I want the basic operation working so I could continue to more complicated examples and in the end production use and real distributed mapping-combining-reducing.

I'd be very gratefull of any kind of help. I'm stuck in this now (many many hours ...). If you need any extra data to help in finding solution I'll send them.

Comment: Thank you Jim for making this better question!

Answer (score 2):

You're not implementing the reducer correctly. It should be:

```
public static class E_EReduce extends Reducer<Text, FloatWritable, Text, FloatWritable>
{
    @Override
    public void reduce( Text key, Iterable<FloatWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
```

Never forget `@Override`, otherwise the compiler won't catch the error.

Comment: I made the changes and behaviour is similar than before. I want mapper to output:

Comment: New trial; my 5 min commenting time exeeded:I made the changes and behaviour is similar than before. I want mapper output to be 25022016 -10.3<end of line>25022016 -17.6<end of line> ... and hope that the reducer gets as key this same date and as values all sixty temperatures that I can iterate through. Why aren't temperatures with similar key (= 25022016) combined together and I can't iterate them all in one reduce call ? Is this about reducer settings, global hadoop configuration or what else ? Thank you anyway for help!

Answer (score 1):

Now I notice what was the problem:

line:

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

said no reducers. I changed it to `job.setNumReduceTasks(1);` and even removed it totally and now the program runs. Why it was there ? => because in a trouble you try everything possible and don't have time to read documents.

Thank you all folks that participated. I go on studying this system.

Comment: removing it totally is equivalent to the default `job.setNumReduceTasks(1);`